# MySQL date difference check within a trigger

Tags: mysql, date, triggers, date-format, datediff

Within a trigger before I insert some data into a table, I would want it to check, whether the difference of dates of events I am entering is greater than or equal to 1 day. There can only be one event in one club taking place each day.

**Sample story**

If there already is `2014-01-01 19:00:00` date in database and I'm trying to insert another record with `2014-01-01` date (hour does not matter), it **should not allow it**.

**Partial code from the trigger**

```
DECLARE k INT DEFAULT 0;

/* This is where I get the error, ABS is to make it always positive to go through  
checking, so that it wont matter whether the NEW date is before or after */

SELECT ABS(DATEDIFF(DATE_FORMAT(`performance_date`, '\'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s\''), 
DATE_FORMAT(NEW.`performance_date`, '\'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s\''))) INTO k;

/* Below code is out of scope for this question */

IF k = 0 THEN
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '58005'
    SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Wrong! Only 1 performance in 1 club is allowed per day! Change your date, or club!';
END IF;
```

> Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'performance_date' in 'field list'

I've tried something as simple as:

```
...DATEDIFF(`performance_date`, NEW.`performance_date`)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `SELECT ... INTO var_list` query to `COUNT` how many entries are already in the database that match your times:

I'm assuming that you mean one entry per day, and I'm assuming that the `performance_date` column is of `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP` type.

```
DECLARE k INT DEFAULT 0;

/* Count number of performances occurring on the same date as the 
   performance being inserted */
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM tbl
WHERE performance_date
BETWEEN DATE(NEW.`performance_date`)
AND DATE(DATE_ADD(NEW.`performance_date`, INTERVAL 1 DAY))
INTO k;

/* If k is not 0, error as there is already a performance */
IF k != 0 THEN
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '58005'
    SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Wrong! Only 1 performance in 1 club is allowed per day! Change your date, or club!';
END IF;
```

For clarity, if you have a performance with `performance_date` as 2014-01-01 19:00:00, and you insert a new performance with date 2014-01-01 08:30:00 (for example) then the above code will run this query, which will return a COUNT of 1, which will then cause the trigger to give that error:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM tbl
WHERE performance_date
BETWEEN DATE("2014-01-01 08:30:00") AND DATE(DATE_ADD("2014-01-01 08:30:00", INTERVAL 1 DAY))
# The line above will become:
# BETWEEN "2014-01-01" AND "2014-01-02"
INTO k
```

Comment: And what if `performance_date` is between `NEW.performance_date` and `NEW.performance_date - 1` ?

Comment: Using your example in the question, `NEW.performance_date - 1` would equal `2013-12-31 19:00:00`, so anything from `2013-12-31 19:00:00` until `2013-12-31 23:59:59` would be on a different day (which I understood to be OK) and everything from `2014-01-01 00:00:00` until `2014-01-01 23:59:59` would match the query and therefore be flagged up as "there's already an event on the day you're trying to add a new event to".

Comment: Do you mean that there must be 24 hours between performances? Not just that you can't have two events on any one day?

Comment: No worries, and nope, I used sqlfiddle.com to check that `DATE_ADD()` worked right, but just used my brain :)

Comment: Working as expected. Thanks.